# Series objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed on Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, api

I have the following dataframe:

df1:

```
          Revenue    Earnings       Date
Year
2017  43206832000  4608790000 2017-01-01
2018  43462740000  8928258000 2018-01-01
2019  44268171000  5001014000 2019-01-01
2020  43126472000  4770527000 2020-01-01
```

I am using an api to get the excahnge currency, the api is CurrencyConverter, the link is:
https://pypi.org/project/CurrencyConverter/

I am trying to add a column to my dataframe to show me the exchange rate of that date, I used the method:

```
c.convert(100, 'EUR', 'USD', date=date(2013, 3, 21))
```

My code is:

```
c = CurrencyConverter()
earnings['exchange_rate'] = c.convert(1, 'BRL', 'USD', earnings['Date'])
print(earnings)
```

I get an answer that says:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I would like to get the following:

```
        Revenue    Earnings       Date    exchange_rate
Year
2017  43206832000  4608790000 2017-01-01  0.305
2018  43462740000  8928258000 2018-01-01  0.305
2019  44268171000  5001014000 2019-01-01  0.295
2020  43126472000  4770527000 2020-01-01  0.249
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter

# if "Date" column isn't already converted:
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

c = CurrencyConverter(fallback_on_missing_rate=True)    # without fallback_on_missing_rate=True I get `BRL has no rate for 2017-01-01` error.
df["exchange_rate"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda x: c.convert(1, "BRL", "USD", x))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          Revenue    Earnings       Date  exchange_rate
Year                                                   
2017  43206832000  4608790000 2017-01-01       0.306034
2018  43462740000  8928258000 2018-01-01       0.304523
2019  44268171000  5001014000 2019-01-01       0.258538
2020  43126472000  4770527000 2020-01-01       0.249114
```